# Tool_tip not showing in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tooltip

my problem is that my tool tip doesn't show when mouse hover over specific button even the same code worked on the main form (this is another form), so i want to figure out what's the problem. Note: i didn't change anything regarding the tool tip settings just like timing...

so, here's my code:

```
private void TVShowPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2 dd = new Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2
    {
        Tag = ll[0].episodeTitle + "\n" + ll[0].episodeOverview,
        Size = new Size(40, 40),
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
    }
    dd.MouseHover += Dd_MouseHover;
}

private void Dd_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2 tmp = (Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2)sender;
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(tmp, tmp.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Any help is appreciated by advance.

Comment: so, any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering the event of mouse hover and setting every time the text for the tool tip of your button, you should add it as soon as you create your button. The tooltip has already build in events for mouse hover, so you don't really need to implement this. Your code should be like that instead:

```
private void TVShowPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2 dd = new Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuThinButton2
    {
        Tag = ll[0].episodeTitle + "\n" + ll[0].episodeOverview,
        Size = new Size(40, 40),
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
    }
    tooltip1.SetToolTip(dd, dd.Tag.ToString());
}
```

You also want to make sure your tooltip property `Active` set to true.

Comment: in my main form it will work normally but here nothing happens, i can't understand why!

Comment: Try with the original button same thing instead of the custom button. If the original button works and the custom not, something is wrong with the custom button implementation.